# Why function doesn't return after else statement in nested functions?

Tags: python, if-statement, return, conditional-statements, nested-function

```
def test1():
    def test2():
        if False:
            return 1
        else: return 2
    test2()
```

I don't know why, but this function isn't returning the 2 it should return. But when we do that:

```
def test1():
    def test2():
        if False:
            return 1
        else: print(2)
    test2()
```

It prints the 2 on the screen.
Why this is happening?

PS: I know we don't need this `else` to return 2 if the if condition is `False`. But I'm curious because if we use this test2 as not being a nested function, it returns 2 without a problem.

Comment: Change `test2()` to `return test2()`  A function call receives the return value of the returned function to the local scope.  If you want it to return out of the current scope you have to return it there as well.

Comment: You need `return test2()`

Comment: Because `test1` *doesn't return anything so it will by default return `None`

Answer (score 2):

`test1` calls `test2`, but doesn't return anything itself, so it implicitly returns `None`. It seems like you meant to return the call to `test2`:

```py
def test1():
    def test2():
        if False:
            return 1
        else: 
            return 2
    return test2() # Here!
```